# Angular overaly of progress spinner is not showing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, progress-bar, overlay

I am copying the project at https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-progress-spinner?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts to test a progress spinner on an overlay. The original code seems successful on the StackBlitz, but not on my end. After I click the button, the progress spinner simply is not showing. I am using Angular 15. Is there anything else I need to add or change?

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) **directly in your question**. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question.

Comment: Also since your linked code example works just fine... how is anyone supposed to guess at why it does not work in a project that you haven't shared any code for?  No one can help you with code in a project where we can see it and the only thing we know is that it doesn't work

Comment: I'm struggeling with the same thing, but at least I think I know why your linked sample works; in the package.json I see "@angular/material": "5.2.1", which is not version 15 that you want to use in your project.